# How to send voice messages to specific landline number on button click in android

Tags: android, button, sms, phone-call

I want to send voice message to specific landline number on button click. Is it possible to make this call?

Any help will be appreciated..

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can leave a voice message after the landline is not responded and after some time a beep is heard and you can leave your voice message after that beep.

Comment: Nope, only I want to send voice message @Chippy

Answer (score 0):

Nexmo provides exciting voice / IVR calling options. You have to explore it accordingly. They even reply to your queries.
https://www.nexmo.com/
It is a paid API free for only few limited users. You have to register with Nexmo and follow the following link:
https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/voice-api/call
You have to call the apis with defined parameters and you are done

Comment: Okay, but I didn't gettinghow to use it @AndroidLearner

Comment: Thanks but its not useful for me. @AndroidLearner